# Worth replacing keyboard on 10 year old laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboards, upgrade

I have a 10 year old Acer Aspire 5750g, and the keyboard has just died on me. Am thinking about replacing it.

I've taken pretty good care of this laptop and kept it relatively dust free, although I have used it for some light gaming (Half Life 2, Bioshock, etc) at times. So far I've replaced the hard drive, RAM and battery, and it's still going strong. I'm wondering whether it's worth paying $20 for a new keyboard when the motherboard or processor or fans may die at any time, given the laptop's age. Would you take the risk?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's worth the risk you should evaluate yourself, it's your money and your laptop

Answer (score 0):

I would just get a USB keyboard. Then if your computer dies, you can still use it on your next computer.

Try out a cheap mechanical keyboard like [this one](https://a.co/d/6BsmJ2i). You wont go back.

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners for I hope obvious security reasons

Comment: a.co is the link automatically generated when you click "share" on amazon. I can try to copy from the url bar if it is a concern.